# How to change a field of fullcalendar io through html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, fullcalendar

I have it set up like so

```
$('#calendar_dash').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month'
    },
    height: 400,
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:30:00',
    forceEventDuration: true,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: events,
    eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        if (jsEvent.url)
            window.location = view.url;

    }
});
```

But now lets say I want the height to be modifiable through the template  I am calling using it in. How can I do this?

If I am simply using it in the html like this

```
<div id="calendar_dash"></div>
```

How can I pass a height from the template of say 600?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a data attribute on the `div` to pass a configurable height:

```
<div id="calendar_dash" data-height="{{ calendar_height }}"></div>
```

... where `calendar_height` is an integer that you have passed to the template context.

Then in your JS:

```
var calendar_div = $('#calendar_dash');

calendar_div.fullCalendar({
    // ...
    height: calendar_div.data("height"),
    //...
});
```

You may want to enhance this a bit to fall back to some default if the data attribute is not specified.